# ActionController::UrlGenerationError - Rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

**Erro message**:

> No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"pictures",
>   :artist_id=>#, :format=>nil} missing required
>   keys: [:artist_id]

**My models:**

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable, dependent: :destroy
end

class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end
```

**PicturesController:**

```
class PicturesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_artist
  respond_to :js, :html

  def create
    @picture = @artist.pictures.new(picture_params)
    if @picture.save
      redirect_to @artist, notice: 'Thanks for your comment'
    else
   end
  end

  def destroy
    @picture = @artist.pictures.find(params[:id])
    @picture.destroy
  end

  private
  def load_artist
    @artist = Artist.find(params[:artist_id])
  end

  def picture_params
    params.require(:picture).permit(:image, :info, :imageable_id, :imageable_type)
  end
end
```

**Routes.rb**

```
resources :artists do
  resources :pictures
end
```

In the view artist/show I call: *<%= render file: 'pictures/new' %>.*
The view pictures/new has the line of code that triggers the error, wich is:

```
<%= form_for([@artist, @artist.pictures.new], html: {multpart: true}) do |f| %>
continue...
```

I could not identify what is wrong. The requested action should be 'create' instead 'index'. Can someone help me, please.

**News** - I didn't understand why, but when I changed this:

> *<%= form_for(:picture, url: [@artist, @artist.pictures.new], html: {multpart: true}) do |f| %>*

, aparently is working. I'll make more tests.

Comment: Did you have generate a scaffold for Pictures if so try to see if you have errors by accessing localhos:3000/pictures than add/edit/delete pictures. If everything is ok, now you could work on your nesting-form for artist-show

Comment: Pictures are most dependent on an artist, they don't need the actions like index or show. So that is a nested resource. In any case, I tried yours suggestions, but didn't work. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

there is many errors.
For your error output. It says that you don't have an action index in your Controller (pictures)

1--

```
No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"pictures", :artist_id=>#, :format=>nil} missing required keys: [:artist_id]

class PicturesController < ApplicationController
   #def index

   #end
end
```

2---
this should have in 'permit' artist_id

```
def picture_params
    params.require(:picture).permit(:image, :info, :imageable_id, :imageable_type)
  end
```

3--

```
<%= form_for @picture, html: {multpart: true} do |f| %>
```

Comment: Pictures are most dependent on an artist, they don't need the actions like index or show. So that is a nested resource. In any case, I tried yours suggestions, but didn't work.